# Dynamically producing sound in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, audio, pcm

I want to produce a Sine wave whose amplitude and frequency can be varied dynamically. I can't use a pre-existing audio file for this. The [documentation for the package `media`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes) says:

> In some cases the container format might simply be an elementary stream containing the encoded data.

I intend to play audio using a stream of values, which represent amplitude (pulse code modulation).
This is a pseudo-code of what I am aiming for:

```
double frequency;
double interval; //interval between successive additions to the audio stream
double time = 0;
streamObject; //some stream object which contains amplitudes as integers in range [-128,128]

while (true){
    double value = Math.sin(time*2*Math.PI*frequency);
    streamObject.write( (int)(value*128) ); //this is some method which will append values to the end of the stream
    time += interval;
    wait(interval); //appending values in real-time because there may be changes to the frequency
}
```

My problem is that the only constructor for class [`Media`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) takes a URI parameter. It is the same for [`AudioClip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)). I was hoping that they would take a `Stream` as a parameter.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be helpful.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-synth.html

Comment: Maybe you can translate this to `JavaFX` while you learn. https://www.developer.com/java/java-sound-creating-playing-and-saving-synthetic-sounds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to do what you want, currently, with JavaFX, as far as I know.

I recommend using `javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine` for your output line. I've used this class for both a real-time theremin-like program, a real-time FM-synthesizer, and an open-source, enhanced version of `Clip` called [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue).

The basic plan would be something like the following:

1. Open an output line (`SourceDataLine`) with a given `AudioFormat`
2. Generate PCM values (e.g., floats ranging from -1 to 1) that represent the desired waveform (one buffer's worth)
3. Translate the PCM to bytes as required by the `AudioFormat`
4. Write using the `SourceDataLine` method [write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int))
5. Loop back to (2) for the duration of the sound

Comment: Which programming language would be best suited to achieving this task in a direct manner?

Comment: Personal choice? I don't know enough about diff languages to give an authoritative answer. AFAIK, C++ and Java are top options, giving you low-level access and fast processing (and good IDE support). I chose Java, in part because of easy access to the sound system (in C, you have to manage another layer for audio access, e.g., a .net framework) and Java's multi-threading. But most of the commercial products out there are built with some flavor of C, I think. I've been told some of the math for convolution (in filtering) can be more readily optimized in C.